# Are iOS game controllers compatible with Apple TV?

Tags: ios, appletv, games

If a game controller mentions that it's compatible with iOS, is it likely that it's also compatible with the Apple TV?

Tons of controllers are iOS compatible, but only a subset of them claim to be compatible with Apple TV. As the Apple TV's tvOS and iOS share many similarities (tvOS is a modified version of iOS), and many games work on both platforms, it seems reasonable that the game controllers would be universal.

I understand that even if it is *likely* that controllers are universally compatible, individual controllers may not be. Really, I'm just wondering/hoping that Apple TV compatibility is something left off of marketing materials because it's a much less popular platform than iOS, but the compatibility is actually there.

Comment: I think this question could be closed as being too broad.  There's no answer that would be correct for most, or all, game controllers.  Can you [edit] it to focus on a specific game controller?

Comment: @fsb Hmm… that's a good point. The question is intentionally broad, I guess. That's why I wrote "...is it _likely_ that…". I want to know if compatibility is likely… with the understanding that individual controllers may or may not be compatible. I'll see if I can make some edits to the question.